# CDGLF: TMN to APL

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, compiler

In this challenge you will remove one of my least favorite features, operator precedence from traditional math notation, to acheive the syntax of one of my favorite languages, APL. The APL subset we will be working with includes only a few functions and single digit numbers. (No arrays!)

### Here is the grammar of the input

(in [pegjs](https://pegjs.org) notation, with `/` representing disjunction and `[]` representing a set of possible characters. If you would like to test it out and validate inputs/outputs you can go to https://pegjs.org/online and paste it in the grammar textbox)

```javascript
Expr = Addition;
Addition = Multiplication [+-] Addition / Multiplication;
Multiplication = Power [*/] Multiplication / Power;
Power = Floor '^' Expr / Floor;
Floor = '[' Expr ']' / '{' Expr '}' / Paren;
Paren = '(' Expr ')' / Digit;
Digit = [0-9];
```

- In descending order of precedence, the infix operators are `^` (exponentiation), `*` or `/`, and `+` or `-`.
- All the operators are left-associative except for `^`. (`0-1-2` is `(0-1)-2` but `0^1^2` is `0^(1^2)`)
- There are no prefix operators.

### And the output format:

```javascript
Expr = Multiplication / Addition / Power / Floor;
Multiplication = Floor [*/] Expr;
Addition = Floor [+-] Expr;
Power = Floor '^' Expr;
Floor = '[' Expr / '{' Expr / Paren;
Paren = '(' Expr ')' / [0-9];
```

- `{` and `[` are prefix and don't need a closing `]` or `}`.
- All operators, prefix *and* infix, have the same precedence.
- All operators are right-associative, so `0o1o2` is the same as `0o(1o2)` for any infix operator `o`.
- The infix operators are `+-*/^` (`^` is for exponentiation, and `*` and `/` are for multiplication and division respectively), and the prefix operators are `{` and `[`, which represent floor and ceiling respectively.

Note that these don't handle whitespace or negation and your program doesn't have to either.

### Task

You are to take an `Expr` in the input format, assumed to be valid, and output an equivalent expression (`Expr`) in the APL-like output format. In this case, equivalent means structurally, so `9` is not a valid output for the input of `3*3`. More specifically, the string that is outputted should have an `Expr` node where the input had an `Expr`, an `Addition` node where the input had `Addition`, etc. with the exception that in the output where an `Expr` node would be placed there may instead be a `Paren` node (this rule is recursive).

### Examples:

These are not necessarily the only answers. Any amount of parentheses are allowed in the output.

```
input        output
1+1          1+1
2*2+1        (2*2)+1
3-5/2+1      (3-(5/2))+1
3-5/(2+1)    3-5/2+1
2*{2+1}      2*{2+1
5^4+1        (5^4)+1
{2+1}+1      ({2+1)+1
3^2^2        3^2^2
(3^2)^2      (3^2)^2
```

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code per language wins. Your function or program takes a string from arguments or stdin and outputs through return or stdout etc. etc.

Comment: [Sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/22112#22112)

Comment: Suggested test cases: `{2+1}+1` (turned into `({2+1)+1`?), `3^2^2` and `(3^2)^2` (both unchanged, I think).

Comment: @Arnauld Those are correct (added, thank you).

Comment: Wait, the input format doesn't include the matching `]`/`}` for floor does it?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms whoops yep, more proof that noone (but you) read my grammars :P. Fixed.

Comment: Input grammar looks wrong. Should be `Add = Add [+-] Mul / Mul`, `Mul = Mul [*/] Pow / Pow`, `Pow = Floor ^ Pow / Floor`.

Comment: @Bubbler Thanks but PEGs can't handle left recursion like `Add = Add`. Maybe I should change it to use repetition so that it gets associativity correct?

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 187 bytes

```
: c ( x -- y ) concat "("")"surround ;
EBNF: A [=[
p=p("*"|"/")e=>[[c]]|e
e=f"^"e=>[[c]]|f
f=("["|"{")s("]"|"}")=>[[2 head c]]|"("s")"=>[[c]]|[0-9]=>[[1string]]
s=s("+"|"-")p=>[[c]]|p
]=]
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBBTwIxFITv/RWTd2ohC7LKwTU10UQNFy7GU9NN1tIFI5balkQC/HbsLkFP8/XNTN5L28akTTi9vc7mLxW8XY7su2sR7ffWOmMjPm1wdg0fbEo7Hz5cQkxZlhF3bDavEE1oklmdKhhw/KAosIOA2TjTJBAnEhS3IWy2bpErT4/z5woPUFIxLz2nAR1oTMLKe6WM1gfLrGyppr9By1rJSeXYnkTkpDMdSXR2iZVtFuhSeVHMmy4ldVXc6u4xOV@rNYsyl4e5XJDwl5xnWurTHjQZTghUDsper4vp@J94RtG7@0xHYgBN65ve7yfnZF3WZVaeQXR0hEL6cmXj1xhBwzb5m34B)</s> Does not work on TIO, but works on 0.98 stable.

Defines a named function `A` which takes a string, parses it, and returns an equivalent expression string in the output format.

Test:

```
{ "1+1" "2*2+1" "3-5/2+1" "3-5/(2+1)" "2*{2+1}"
  "5^4+1" "{2+1}+1" "3^2^2" "(3^2)^2" } [ A print ] each
```

Output:

```
(1+1)
((2*2)+1)
((3-(5/2))+1)
(3-(5/(((2+1)))))
(2*({(2+1)))
((5^4)+1)
(({(2+1))+1)
(3^(2^2))
((((3^2)))^2)
```

Since any number of parentheses are allowed, it is easiest to ignore the operator associativity of APL and parenthesize every single parsed node.

Factor comes with a PEG parser with EBNF syntax [`peg.ebnf`](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-peg.ebnf.html). The grammar nodes `s`, `p`, `e`, and `f` stand for "sum", "product", "exp", and "floor" respectively. The last line is recognized as the "main" grammar, so I moved `s` to the last line.

It does support character classes like `[+-]`, but it is converted to a single character (= integer), not a string, so it is more complicated to post-process. So I decided to simply use disjunction on string literals instead (except for digits).

`=> [[ Factor code ]]` defines how to post-process the grammar. For most of the nodes, it is simply "concatenate all parts and wrap in a pair of parens", which is defined as a named function `c` and reused throughout the code. For floor and ceiling, we only need to keep the opening `{[` and the body, thus `2 head c`.